# Compile Python3.11 with OpenSSL on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile Python3.11 with SSL support (so I can use pip).  I have spent hours recompiling, with a number of options, but still the command

`import ssl` in the REPL leads to the same error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'`

The option I've read to use is `./configure --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl` - which points to the installed openSSL on the system which returns the version `OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022`.

Every thread I've found about this either advises making this setting, OR to change the Setup.dist file, which doesn't exist on 3.11 (I've found `Setup`, but not `.dist`).

I need to run 3.11 because of the project, so the system 3.9 Python isn't an option (import ssl works fine on the system python).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt install libssl-dev`. It worked for me.

From my understanding, python is looking for `ssl` C headers, which are not part of standard `openssl` install.